# datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

This question is already asked many times but none of them worked for me. I am trying to use this date picker in a `JSP` file. This is my script

```
<head>
<title>My Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="../resource/css/page-style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="../resource/css/jQuery-ui.css" />
<script src="../resource/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../resource/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../resource/js/form-elements.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#shortcuts").load("shortcut.html");
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    alert('jQuery is working');
});
</script>
</head>
```

The `shortcut` file is loading perfectly, alert is also showing. I get error message as `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`. I am not facing this problem if I run this script in a html file placed in my desktop, when I copy the come code to my IDE and run it I get this error in my console. Please suggest me what can I do? I know this question is asked several times I have checked every answer this is the only [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709197/using-jquery-datepicker-in-a-jsp/13709402#13709402) having close match to my prob but didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't think so. The same `head` tag I have in other file. Working perfectly.

Comment: make sure you have `DOM` with id of `datepicker` and also make sure `ID` is unique.

Comment: code seems fine.. makesure your ui is loaded.. view source of your page and click the jquery-ui link in firefox to check if ui is loaded or not

Comment: check that your `js` files has loaded properly or not.. You can see it with the help of `firebug`

Comment: Checked for repeating id. NO Ids are unique. Checking for js files loaded or not may be this could help

Comment: it will be much bettter if you post a fiddle here http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212696/jquery-ui-datepicker-datepicker-is-not-a-function/41435294#41435294

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is with your imported files.I think you have not placed them properly.

Try to import these files

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

It is working for me.

see here for more [information](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: Replacing the relative source to the url works file. But, why? any guess?

Comment: copy the same files now into your folder.then try

Comment: @Dibya whatever the files you are using previously they may not correct.otherwise the path what you gave is not correct

Comment: @Dibya are you copying those files

Comment: I was trying, I can refer to my jquery-ui.js file correctly but the reference file is not working locally. I have this code now: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`
`<script src="../resource/js/jQuery-ui.js"></script>` and this is working. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26220/discussion-between-dibya-and-psr)

Answer (score 20):

Double check that there are no JQuery references *after* your JQuery-ui reference.

I had an extra JQuery reference that came after my JQuery-ui reference and lost an hour chasing the problem.  That will cause the datepicker not found error.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: This answer needs to be on the top :)

Comment: i had jquery imported by DataTable, then I referenced jquery ui,
Then various references of jquery were referenced by the extensions installed in my chrome browser, therefore i was getting this error.
<br>Now I am writing what worked for me, I moved the reference to jquery ui to the bottom of the page. IT WORKED

Answer (score 1):

This is something to do with the import files. I also faced the same scenario and following imports helped me to overcome the following issue "**datepicker is not a function**".

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```