# Jquery datetimepicker() in ajax tabcontainer

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having Ajax tab Container in my asp.net page.
I am using jquery to select date by clicking in the textbox. But jquery is not working in the Ajax tab container.

below is the code that i am using.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datecontrol").datepicker();
        });

    </script>
 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
    </ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div class="Wrapper">
        <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" CssClass="fancy fancy-green"
            ActiveTabIndex="0">
            <ajax:TabPanel ID="tbpnluser" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    New Patient</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="UserReg" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" runat="server" CssClass="datecontrol"></asp:TextBox>
 </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>
 </ajax:TabContainer>
 </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` is not working because you didn't include `jQuery library` on your `HTML page`.

Include the `latest jquery library` from here:

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426255/jspdatepicker-is-not-a-function/15426543) you need to import the following files.You only included css file not js file.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not included the id of the textbox in the script..Do this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtDob").datepicker();
    });
```

Also u should include jquery as shown below..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

for more information see this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)